# Make the TextBox size adapt to column size in GridView wpf?

Tags: wpf, xaml, gridview, textbox

Hi I am using a `TextBox` inside a `GridView` column cell.

I am correctly able to place and bind the data for the `TextBox` in the 'Parameter' column.

```
<ListView Margin="5"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Variables}"
          Grid.Column="0"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Width="570">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Type" Width="40"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Parameter" Width="80">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding ParameterName}"
                                 Padding="0"
                                 Margin="0"
                                 Width="Auto"
                                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Expression" Width="80"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Value" Width="50"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Default Value" Width="80"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Value Type" Width="80"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Show in UI" Width="80"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Description" Width="80"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I want such that the `TextBox` width correctly adapts to the width of the 'Parameter' column, even when I try to resize the columns.
I have tried setting the `Width` and `HorizontalContentAlignment` properties of `TextBox` but was not succesful.

Right now it looks like as below:

[image: ListView with TextBox in the 'Parameter' column]

Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an item container style for `ListViewItem` that sets the `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch`. You can remove the `HorizontalContentAlignment` attribute from the `TextBox`.

```
<ListView Margin="5"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Variables}"
          Grid.Column="0"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Width="570">
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
      </Style>
   </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Type" Width="40"/>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Parameter" Width="80">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBox Text="{Binding ParameterName}"
                           Padding="0"
                           Margin="0"
                           Width="Auto"/>
               </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         </GridViewColumn>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Expression" Width="80"/>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Value" Width="50"/>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Default Value" Width="80"/>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Value Type" Width="80"/>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Show in UI" Width="80"/>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Description" Width="80"/>
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```